# Special End-line characters/string from lines read from text file, using Python

Tags: python

I need to read lines from a text file but, where the 'end of line' caracter is not always \n or \x or a combination and may be any combination of characters like 'xyz' or '|', but the 'end of line' is always the same and known for each type of file.

As the text file may be a big one and I have to keep performances and memory usage in mind what seems to be the best solution ?
Today I use a combinaison of string.read(1000) and split(myendofline) or partition(myendofline)  but I would know if a more elegant and standard solution exists.

Comment: if your delimiter was just 1 character, you can use the csv module.

Comment: alas..no it 'may be any combination of characters like 'xyz''

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's ***a generator function*** thats acts as an ***iterator*** on a file, cuting the lines according exotic newline being identical in all the file.

It reads the file by chunks of `lenchunk` characters and displays the lines in each current chunk, chunk after chunk.

**Since the newline is 3 characters in my exemple (':;:'), it may happen that a chunk ends with a cut newline: this generator function takes care of this possibility and manages to display the correct lines.**

In case of a newline being only one character, the function could be simplified. I wrote only the function for the most delicate case.

Employing this function allows to read a file one line at a time, without reading the entire file into memory.

```
from random import randrange, choice


# this part is to create an exemple file with newline being :;:
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz '
ch = ':;:'.join(''.join(choice(alphabet) for nc in xrange(randrange(0,40)))
                for i in xrange(50))
with open('fofo.txt','wb') as g:
    g.write(ch)


# this generator function is an iterator for a file
# if nl receives an argument whose bool is True,
# the newlines :;: are returned in the lines

def liner(filename,eol,lenchunk,nl=0):
    # nl = 0 or 1 acts as 0 or 1 in splitlines()
    L = len(eol)
    NL = len(eol) if nl else 0
    with open(filename,'rb') as f:
        chunk = f.read(lenchunk)
        tail = ''
        while chunk:
            last = chunk.rfind(eol)
            if last==-1:
                kept = chunk
                newtail = ''
            else:
                kept = chunk[0:last+L]   # here: L
                newtail = chunk[last+L:] # here: L
            chunk = tail + kept
            tail = newtail
            x = y = 0
            while y+1:
                y = chunk.find(eol,x)
                if y+1: yield chunk[x:y+NL] # here: NL
                else: break
                x = y+L # here: L
            chunk = f.read(lenchunk)
        yield tail
    


for line in liner('fofo.txt',':;:'):
    print line
```

Here's the same, with printings here and there to allow to follow the algorithm.

```
from random import randrange, choice


# this part is to create an exemple file with newline being :;:
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz '
ch = ':;:'.join(''.join(choice(alphabet) for nc in xrange(randrange(0,40)))
                for i in xrange(50))
with open('fofo.txt','wb') as g:
    g.write(ch)


# this generator function is an iterator for a file
# if nl receives an argument whose bool is True,
# the newlines :;: are returned in the lines

def liner(filename,eol,lenchunk,nl=0):
    L = len(eol)
    NL = len(eol) if nl else 0
    with open(filename,'rb') as f:
        ch = f.read()
        the_end = '\n\nxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'+\
                  '\nend of the file=='+ch[-50:]+\
                  '\nxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\n'
        f.seek(0,0)
        chunk = f.read(lenchunk)
        tail = ''
        while chunk:
            if (chunk[-1]==':' and chunk[-3:]!=':;:') or chunk[-2:]==':;':
                wr = [' ##########---------- cut newline cut ----------##########'+\
                     '\nchunk== '+chunk+\
                     '\n---------------------------------------------------']
            else:
                wr = ['chunk== '+chunk+\
                     '\n---------------------------------------------------']
            last = chunk.rfind(eol)
            if last==-1:
                kept = chunk
                newtail = ''
            else:
                kept = chunk[0:last+L]   # here: L
                newtail = chunk[last+L:] # here: L
            wr.append('\nkept== '+kept+\
                      '\n---------------------------------------------------'+\
                      '\nnewtail== '+newtail)
            chunk = tail + kept
            tail = newtail
            wr.append('\n---------------------------------------------------'+\
                      '\ntail + kept== '+chunk+\
                      '\n---------------------------------------------------')
            print ''.join(wr)
            x = y = 0
            while y+1:
                y = chunk.find(eol,x)
                if y+1: yield chunk[x:y+NL] # here: NL
                else: break
                x = y+L # here: L
            print '\n\n==================================================='
            chunk = f.read(lenchunk)
        yield tail
        print the_end
    


for line in liner('fofo.txt',':;:',1):
    print 'line== '+line
```

.

EDIT

I compared the times of execution of my code and of the chmullig's code.

With a 'fofo.txt' file about 10 MB, created with

```
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz '
ch = ':;:'.join(''.join(choice(alphabet) for nc in xrange(randrange(0,60)))
                for i in xrange(324000))
with open('fofo.txt','wb') as g:
    g.write(ch)
```

and measuring times like that:

```
te = clock()
for line in liner('fofo.txt',':;:', 65536):
    pass
print clock()-te


fh = open('fofo.txt', 'rb')
zenBreaker = SpecialDelimiters(fh, ':;:', 65536)

te = clock()
for line in zenBreaker:
    pass
print clock()-te
```

I obtained the following minimum times observed on several essays:

> ............my code 0,7067 seconds
>
> chmullig's code 0.8373 seconds

.

EDIT 2

I changed my generator function: `liner2()` takes a file-handler instead of the file's name. So the opening of the file can be put out of the measuring of time, as it is for the measuring of chmullig's code

```
def liner2(fh,eol,lenchunk,nl=0):
    L = len(eol)
    NL = len(eol) if nl else 0
    chunk = fh.read(lenchunk)
    tail = ''
    while chunk:
        last = chunk.rfind(eol)
        if last==-1:
            kept = chunk
            newtail = ''
        else:
            kept = chunk[0:last+L]   # here: L
            newtail = chunk[last+L:] # here: L
        chunk = tail + kept
        tail = newtail
        x = y = 0
        while y+1:
            y = chunk.find(eol,x)
            if y+1: yield chunk[x:y+NL] # here: NL
            else: break
            x = y+L # here: L
        chunk = fh.read(lenchunk)
    yield tail

fh = open('fofo.txt', 'rb')
te = clock()
for line in liner2(fh,':;:', 65536):
    pass
print clock()-te
```

The results, after numerous essays to see the minimum times, are

> .........with liner()  0.7067seconds
>
> .......with liner2() 0.7064 seconds
>
> chmullig's code 0.8373 seconds

In fact the opening of the file counts for an infinitesimal part in the total time.

Comment: @philnext @chmullig I wish to know if other persons oberve the same order in the timings of execution. I knew that the string method ``find()`` is extremely fast, that's why I used it. But I'd like to have confirmation of timings performed on other machines than mine.

Comment: with another text file :  with liner : 1.26600003242 seconds  with liner2 :
1.23399996758 seconds

Comment: @philnext Thank you. A lot of execution's times must be measured for each function, because this time is variable according what happens elsewhere in the computer. From a lot of measures, the minimum one is the best to evaluate the "absolute" speed of a code. I think you didn't obtain these results on a lot of essays, because in my opinion the times with liner and with liner2 are epsilon-different. -- But what I wonder about is to verify on other machines that my code with liner or liner2 is really faster than the code of chmullig.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously simplest would be to just read the whole thing and then call `.split('|')`.

However if that's undesirable because it requires you to read the whole thing into memory  you might read in arbitrary chunks and perform the split on them. You could write a class that grabs another arbitrary chunk when the current one runs out, and the rest of your application doesn't need to know about it.

Here's the input, zen.txt

```
The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters||Beautiful is better than ugly.|Explicit is better than implicit.|Simple is better than complex.|Complex is better than complicated.|Flat is better than nested.|Sparse is better than dense.|Readability counts.|Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.|Although practicality beats purity.|Errors should never pass silently.|Unless explicitly silenced.|In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.|There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.|Although that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch.|Now is better than never.|Although never is often better than *right* now.|If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.|If the implementation is easy to explain, it may be a good idea.|Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!
```

Here's my little test case, that works for me. It doesn't handle a whole bunch corner cases, nor is it particularly pretty, but it should get you started.

```
class SpecialDelimiters(object):
    def __init__(self, filehandle, terminator, chunksize=10):
        self.file = filehandle
        self.terminator = terminator
        self.chunksize = chunksize
        self.chunk = ''
        self.lines = []
        self.done = False

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        if self.done:
            raise StopIteration
        try:
            return self.lines.pop(0)
        except IndexError:
            #The lines list is empty, so let's read some more!
            while True:
                #Looping so even if our chunksize is smaller than one line we get at least one chunk
                newchunk = self.file.read(self.chunksize)
                self.chunk += newchunk
                rawlines = self.chunk.split(self.terminator)
                if len(rawlines) > 1 or not newchunk:
                    #we want to keep going until we have at least one block
                    #or reached the end of the file
                    break
            self.lines.extend(rawlines[:-1])
            self.chunk = rawlines[-1]
            try:
                return self.lines.pop(0)
            except IndexError:
                #The end of the road, return last remaining stuff
                self.done = True
                return self.chunk               

zenfh = open('zen.txt', 'rb')
zenBreaker = SpecialDelimiters(zenfh, '|')
for line in zenBreaker:
    print line
```

Comment: +1, good that you made chunk size an option. however, you're not handling quoted lines, but I don't think you need to worry about that.

Comment: Ah, you mean if they include `\|` or something? Don't do that! ;)

Comment: Ah, I didn't see the edit when I started on the code. There's an [old ticket](http://bugs.python.org/issue1152248) about this for python which doesn't have many other, better solutions either.

Comment: @chmullig With ``|`` as separator of lines, the beginning of your 'zen.txt' contains a blank line between ``The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters`` and ``Beautiful is better than ugly.`` But your code displays only two lines, without the blank line.

Comment: eyquem, good catch. It's actually worse than that, as it was originally posted! In transfering from ipython -> stackoverflow I left off the `.pop(0)` and just had `.pop()` which reversed the order of certain subchunks of lines. Edited to correct.

Answer (score 1):

Given your contraints, it maybe would be best to convert the known unusual newlines to *normal* newlines first and then use the usual:

```
for line in file:
    ...
```

Comment: Good idea but not for my problem with big (+/- 500 Mo) files

Answer (score 1):

`TextFileData.split(EndOfLine_char)` seems to be your solution.
If it's not working fast enough, then you should consider using a lower-level programming level.